# push object array into array by index

Tags: javascript, arrays

l know my question is similar for too many questions. l have checked all answers and all answers are not give me what l want exactly.

l have this array :

```
[
  {
    "size": true,
    "status": true,
    "desc": "صحن مخلمة",
    "name": "مخلمة",
    "id": "QmzeJgg2F2"
  }
]
```

l want to push new array object by index array above using this code :

```
  items_local: any[] = []; 

  add_addons(index,data) {

    this.items_local[index].addons.push(data.addons);

    console.log(this.items_local);
  }
```

expected output :

```
    [
  {
    "addons": [    // new array pushing
    {
      "price": 10
    },
    {
      "price": 10
    }
    ],
    "size": true,
    "status": true,
    "desc": "صحن مخلمة",
    "name": "مخلمة",
    "id": "QmzeJgg2F2"
  }
]
```

Error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your original object doesn't have a `addons` key, hence you can't call the push property on it, first create that key and assign to empty array

```
  add_addons(index,data) {
    this.items_local[index].addons = []
    this.items_local[index].addons.push(data.addons);

    console.log(this.items_local);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering . He pushing only once.

Comment: l want push too many array not only one array . Now he push only one array

Comment: not sure if I understand this correctly, but you can just check if addons exists before pushing, if it doesnt exist, create it, if it exists skip and push

if(!this.items_local[index].addons) this.items_local[index].addons = []

Comment: l have a question, please. l Want to check if the value exists in the second array before pushing. l did like that `this.items_local[index].addons[index].title===addon.title` . l will get only the first element of the second array. l want to check all elements. How i can do that please?